# How to create a mock instance of IOptions<MyOption>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using `IOptions<>` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options.

I have the following controller.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<SourceController> _logger;
    private readonly MyOptions _option;

    public SourceController(ILogger<SourceController> logger, IOptions<SyncOptions> optionAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _option = optionAccessor.Value;
    }
```

Now I'm creating a unit test setup. How to mock IOptions()?

```
MyTest() { // Test constructor
    var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole(LogLevel.Information).AddDebug().AddNLog();
    loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyController>();

    option = new Options<MyOptions>(); // Error! How to mock IOptions<MyOptions>()?

    app = new MyController(logger, option);
```

Comment: Whenever you think mock, think [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) ;)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use helper class `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options`

Try replacing

```
option = new Options<MyOptions>();
```

with

```
option = Options.Create(new MyOptions());
```

Answer (score 13):

What about:

```cs
var optionsMock = new Mock<IOptions<MyOptions>>();
optionsMock.SetupGet(o => o.Value).Returns(new MyOptions());
```

Comment: This is great for when you DO use mocking.